# Set.size() doesn't match the number of elements in iterator

Tags: java, iterator, size, compiler-errors

Why doesn't Set.size() match the number of elements in the set's iterator?

I'm using a HashSet, and I added some duplicate values.  Those duplicates were automatically eliminated since I used a set.  Set.size() is returning 16.  When I actually iterate over the elements, I get 13.

What can be causing this difference?  Am I doing it right?

```
Set set = new HashSet();
...
System.out.println ("Found " + set.size() + " tokens...");
Iterator it = set.iterator();
int i = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    i++;
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(i) + ": " + (String)it.next());
}
```

Here's the output from the console:

```
Found 16 tokens...
1: 3 Months Free HD Extra Pack
2: Best Buy - $30 for 3 Months (Instant Rebate)
3: Gift Card - Fry's - $100 (HDTV Offer)
4: 6 Months FREE Showtime
5: 3 Months Free HD Access
6: Savings Certificate Booklet
7: 3 months FREE Showtime (rolls off month 4)
8: Free NASCAR Hotpass
9: 3 Months Free DVR Service
10: $0 Delivery & Handling
11: 1 Year Free Showtime
12: $99 Off Advance Equipment (2nd AP)
13: Best Buy - $30 for 12 Months (Instant Rebate)
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. I've just tried this but failed to reproduce it.

Comment: In other words, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) so that we can just copy'n'paste'n'run it without any code changes.

Comment: Does any other thread have access to the HashSet?

Comment: Did you redefine `hashCode()`, `equals()` and `compareTo()`? If so, show the code for them

Comment: what was the answer? c'mon, tell us. we love you.

Comment: My money is on ClassCastException caused by storing something that is not a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously this is not possible. HashSet is a well-established enough class that there is no possibility of a bug like you describe being in it. Here are some ways you could make this happen:

- Screwing around with the set using Reflection like Mark Peters suggests;
- You have caused an exception to be thrown after the 13th element which terminates the program
- Overriding the behavior of Set to make it inconsistent
- You are using different sets for the printout of the total and the items

Comment: After lunch, I couldn't reproduce the same problem.  My code was very straightforward, and my only guess is that I was just having some problem scrolling to the bottom of the output.  As you can see from my output snippet above, I never had a marker for the end of the output -- so I'll never be sure -- but I'm siding with your theory that it was "user error".  Thanks.

Comment: another possibility: your set might contain a 'null' element (HashSets can contain at most one 'null' element in the Set). Some debuggers don't show the 'null' element so that when you compare the list size and the elements, you see a certain listSize but only see listSize-1 elements when inspecting the list.

Answer (score 3):

Because you used reflection:

```
Set set = new HashSet();

Field size = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("size");
size.setAccessible(true);
Field map = HashSet.class.getDeclaredField("map");
map.setAccessible(true);
size.set(map.get(set), 16);

System.out.println("Found " + set.size() + " tokens...");
```

Seriously though, that's the only way I can think of that you'd get these results, assuming you're using the standard HashSet and not some 3rd party one.  Now I can't imagine you would be using reflection to do this and yet wouldn't understand your results, so I assume you're mistaken in something that you're telling us (for instance, set isn't actually local but is accessible by another thread).

Comment: Yup, that would have done it -- but that's not what I did.  Thanks for teaching me a new way to botch my programs.  I'm sure I'll use this inappropriately someday ;)